# Facebook Graph API - How to get business pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I’m integrating app with Facebook to create post to user business pages.
I have completed to request permissions as:
email,public_profile,pages_show_list,pages_manage_posts.
I have created posts to normal pages.
However, I can’t get business pages from user although user have full permissions on these pages.
And user also select these pages to allow my app access while authorizing.

**How can I get the business pages that user allow via Facebook Graph API?**

I research and see that I need request  advance access from business_management permission.
I need make a request to business account to enable “request advance” button to request this permission . I tried to get business user info but FB doesn’t update statistics and enable button.

Please share me your experiences.

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.